# Changing page layout across site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2010, rich-text

I'm trying to customize the OOTB Markup Styles in the Ribbon in SP2010 for the Rich Text Editor. I've found some documentation about the process, and one of the first steps is to add a PrefixStyleSheet attribute to the PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField element in the page layout for layouts that use the Rich HTML Editor.

Making that change to the page layout in SP Designer does remove the OOTB Markup Styles, but I'm wondering how to apply the change across site collections? We have a number of site collections that use the same page layout, but I noticed that when I added the attribute to the page layout in one site collection, that change doesn't carry over to other site collections. Do I need to deploy a feature to make this change? Or is there an easy way to globally change a page layout in all site collections that have that layout?

Answer (score 2):

Page layouts live in the master page gallery and you can't go higher than the site collection. You will need to either manually copy and apply the modified page layout to other site collections or automate it using PowerShell.

You could also develop a feature to deploy your page layout. You would probably end up using PowerShell to activate the feature for all your site collections.

Comment: Or you could use feature stapling to activate the feature on new site collections of certain site templates.

Comment: Yes, that's an option for new site collections. Worth mentioning.